# Improper Subsets, Set Difference

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given sets A, B, and X. If X is an improper subset of B-A, what's the relationship between X and A? X and B?

Answer (score 1):

$X$ and $A$ are disjoint -- nothing more, nothing less. $X$ is also related to $B$ by being a subset of it, which means $X \cap B = X$.  If $A \cap B$ is nonempty, $X$ is a *proper* subset of $B$.